# If $f$ is a continuous analytic function on a unit disc about the origin $D\setminus\{0\}$, then $f$ is also analytic at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

The question defined  as $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous function  analytic on $D \setminus\{ 0\}$, where $D$ is a unit disc about the origin. How can I show that $f$ is also analytic at zero?

I searched the old topics but most of the time the function $f$ was constant or maps itself. I couldn't figure out what $f$ maps. Can we talk about a constant function in this case? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to state the question more carefully. The function $1/z$ is a counterexample to the version you posted.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f$ is continuous on $D.$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich this is the exact question but I am still struggling.

Comment: It's a standard result, in every book on beginning complex analysis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ah thanks!